# PostgreSQL 9.4.1, don't call trigger in cascade deleting

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger "BEFORE DELETE ON my_table".
The table "my_table" contains a FK on "main_table" with a delete on cascade.

How to delete some rows in "main_table" without calling the trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE TRIGGER before_del_trig;
DELETE FROM main_table;
ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE TRIGGER before_del_trig;
COMMIT;
```

That way no other transaction is affected by the disabled trigger.